# Why is there no re-declaration error in this code?

Tags: c, syntax, scope, declaration

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x=3;
int main()
{
  int x=4;
  printf("%d",x);

  return 0;
}
```

As we know a local declaration acts as a global declaration too. Since `x` has been already globally declared as 3, won't a new global declaration (non-tentative) cause a re-declaration error since 'merging' of more than one non-tentative definitions don't happen in case of local declarations ?

Comment: Because there is no redeclaration error.

Comment: who is we? and why do they know that a local declaration acts like a global one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nopes, here comes the [*scope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

The `x` inside `main()` has block scope and overrides (shadows) the *global* `x` inside the `main()`.

Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.1, *"Scopes of identifiers"*, (*emphasis mine*)

> [...] If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end
>   strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). **Within the inner scope, the
>   identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer
>   scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**

Comment: *gcc*'s `-Wshadow` would warn about that, it's specially helpful if you shadow a local declaration inside a `for`, `while` or `if` block.

Comment: In C standard gibberish terms, function scope and block scope are two different things. Function scope refers to goto labels.

Comment: @iharob absolutely right, but then, there's nothing _wrong_ in it, if done purposefully, (example: multiple counters), right?

Comment: @Lundin I was remembering something like that but was not very sure of the exact terminology, so I had put both of them. Now, updated.

Comment: Yes of course, I am talking about accidentally doing it.

Answer (score 2):

> As we know a local declaration acts as a global declaration

No. that's wrong.

Global `x` is not visible to `main` in the presence of local `x`. Compiler will not generate any warning or error as its allowed by C standard. 
Scope of the the variables are different. `x` outside the `main` has global scope while `x` inside the `main` has function scope.